What are these white marks on my outer windows?
We recently moved into a new place, and we we noticed that there are these white markings on the exterior facing windows.


Only specific glasses have it. I think the markings are present all the time. As far as I know they are glasses from the year 2000.
Are these indications that there's something wrong with the glass?

If the glass is double pane, it may be signs that the seal is broken.

RMDman may be right, though it doesn't look like they're double-pane.  Does the white stuff scrape off?  Is it on the inside or outside glass?  Do you own, or rent?

Thanks for the remarks.
To me, it doesn't look like double glass. I own the house, I'll try to have another close look tonight, to answer your questions
